# WIndows Form textbox pass text value to a Powershell Runscript

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, variables

I am developing a **Win form** with C# to create a tool that would run several PowerShell scripts within a **PowerShell Run space** and show the results on a text file.

Right now I have the following.

... a Win-form with a button that will return the results of the PowerShell script below:

```
 txtUserInfo.Text = RunScript(@"Get-ADUser UserNameGoesHere -Properties * | Select-Object Enabled, @{Expression={$_.LockedOut};Label='Locked';}, DisplayName, GivenName, SurName, Mail, @{ Expression ={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}; Label='Last Logon';}, @{Expression={$_.Created};Label='Date Created';}, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires | Format-list");
```

The script is working and is showing the results on a textbox.

[image]

This works with the Users name hard coded into the PowerShell  Script:

> RunScript(@"Get-ADUser **UserNameGoesHere** -Properties * |

I am trying to find a way to use a Textbox for input on the Win form and pass that value to the PowerShell Run space as a variable. But I have not been able to find anything posted that will assist me.

Any pointers are appreciated

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless I am misunderstanding, just add it into the string

```
txtUserInfo.Text = RunScript(@"Get-ADUser " + YourTextBox.Text + @" -Properties * |
  Select-Object Enabled, @{Expression={$_.LockedOut};Label='Locked';}, 
    DisplayName, GivenName, SurName, Mail,
    @{ Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}; Label='Last Logon';},
    @{Expression={$_.Created};Label='Date Created';},
    passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires |
  Format-list");
```

Comment: This worked!. thank you for the solution. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what Sorceri said, you need your button to do all the work, and use the data that was grabbed from your text box.

```
txtUserInfo.Text = RunScript(@"Get-ADUser " + YourTextBox.Text + @" -Properties * | Select-Object Enabled, @{Expression={$_.LockedOut};Label='Locked';}, DisplayName, GivenName, SurName, Mail, @{ Expression ={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}; Label='Last Logon';}, @{Expression={$_.Created};Label='Date Created';}, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires | Format-list");

$yourbutton.Add_Click({
    #do all your stuff
})
```

Comment: yes, I have a button on the form that will execute the code. Regards,